# How to get ServerName/ConnectionString for uBuntu

Tags: c#, mysql, ubuntu

I'm programming a `C#` program and I want to have access to a `MySql` database

I've found a few examples online. The format is:

```
"Server=ServerName;Database=databaseName;Uid=username;Pwd=password;"
```

I was wondering how will I be able to get the server name.

I installed `mysql` to localhost on my `ubuntu` server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your C# code's running on Windows?
If that's the case, you'll need to use the remote server's IP as the server name.
Alternatively you can do start, run, cmd, nslookup *server's ip* - to translate the IP to a hostname, then use that as the server name.

NB: MySQL also needs to allow remote access.  See [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

ServerName is the IP of the Machine, in your case this will be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or the name of the Computer name(I don't know if there something like that in `Ubuntu`.

When researched it looks like you need command hostname. You can check this [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/hostname.1.html)